# Site user visibility and portal user visibility meaning

Tags: experience-cloud, visibility

I am confused about the meaning of the customer user visibility and portal user visibility setting in experience cloud. Can anyone explain what do these two term refer to ?

So far I have understood that portal user visibility actually control what will happen among customer or partner users under the same account while site users visibility means what security setting will be among users in one site of the experience cloud ?

why the wording in the official document is confusing as hell ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_user_sharing.htm&type=5),

**Portal User Visibility**: If enabled, portal users in the same customer or partner portal account can see each other, regardless of the organization-wide defaults. Partner users with a Partner Community license (or equivalent) can also see the Salesforce user that owns their partner portal account.

**Site User Visibility**: This setting controls whether user sharing is available for authenticated users in your org’s communities. If enabled, you have the option of selecting See other members of this community, with turns visibility on or off, on a community-by-community basis.

If any one of above setting is enabled experience cloud site users can see other experience cloud site users in the same account and the same site.

Also, check site user visibility best practices [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_user_visibility_best_practices.htm&type=5).

Comment: silly question, so the users can see each other as long as they belong to the same account? or regardless of the account? I am sorry i am struggling to udnerstand this topic as well